# UITableView loading images after app loads

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

so I'm writing an app, and it fetches album artwork from website URLs.

Basically how I have it written thus far is that a file is read in, which contains URLs to the album artwork. Then a two dimensional NSMutableArray is constructed with data from the file, and UIImages initialized from the individual URLs from the file, and then stored in the array.

The array is then loaded into the UITableView.

This works great... except it takes like, 10 seconds to load the app (lol).

So is there any way to load the images once the UITableView is loaded?

Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath method if it helps.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"]autorelease];
}

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:artistTag]).text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:artistIndex];

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:albumTag]).text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:albumIndex];

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:dateTag]).text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:dateIndex];

((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:imageTag]).image = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

return cell;
```

}

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is because your image retrieving is blocking the main thread.
Use this to manage the images loading asynchronously.

http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/

It includes sample of how to use it

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is load the images in background threads.

For a full suite of related code, check out [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Or for just the Asynchronous View code, checkout [this link](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/)

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is very good for asynchronous loading and even comes with functionality for handling image loading (of Album Artwork, for example).
The github repo includes sample code.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking